# django import error at / no module named pip._vendor.pkg_resources.state_machine

Tags: django, python-2.7, centos

I just tried to install my django app on centos BUT
this weird error is showing up and I really don't know where it is coming from.
I just works fine on simple server.

[Error image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bc21yg4q5qk62q5/Error_Page.png?dl=0).

> "No module named `pip._vendor.pkg_resources.state_machine`" and then 
>   "`{% **url** 'myUrlName'  %}`"

Looking forward to any help.

Comment: Your picture link to Dropbox doesn't work, it gives a 403.